# ZFS issue after enlarging image

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, zfsonlinux, zpool

I created a new img using the following command:

```
truncate -s 250G disk.img
```

and I replace the existing image that I used for zpool with that one using (lxd.img was 2G):

```
zpool replace lxd lxd.img disk.img
```

I set the autoexpand to on

```
sudo zpool set autoexpand=on lxd
```

But the size is still 2GB and I have an EXPANDSZ property that states the size of the new image.

```
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
lxd   1.98G  1.82G   170M      248G    69%    91%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I fixed it using sudo zpool online -e lxd /var/lib/lxd/disk.img

Comment: Also see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/githb/index.html for more details.